# How can i soleve "Full authentication is required to access this resource" at php

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

```
<?php

    $curl = curl_init( 'URL' );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'client_id' => 'NAME:',
    //'redirect_uri' => 'URL',
    'client_secret' => '',
    'username' => 'USERNAME',
    'password' => 'PASSWORD',
    //'code' => $_GET['code'], // The code from the previous request
    'grant_type' => 'AUTHORİZATİON'
    ) );

    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $auth = curl_exec( $curl );
    $secret = json_decode($auth);
    print_r($secret);
    $access_key = $secret->access_token;
?>
```

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: i can't take access token and i take error at last line. How solve this problem

Comment: Try to check the URL on which you are requesting is correct, after that check credentials for client (i.e. cllientId & clientSecret). I don't think that username & password will be needed for OAuth2 request, & change the `grant_type` according to the grant you are using to get an access token. read this : https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//SOLUTION

<? php
$deviceId = "DEVICEID";

$username = 'USERNAME';
$userpwd = 'PASSWORD:';
$url = 'URL';

$params = array(
  "grant_type" => "password",
  "username" => "USERNAME",
  "password" => "PASSWORD"
);

$access_token = getAccessToken($url, $params, $userpwd);
$locationInfo = getLocation($deviceId, $access_token);

print_r($locationInfo);

function getAccessToken($url, $params, $userpwd) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpwd);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  $postData = "";
  foreach($params as $k => $v) {
    $postData. = $k.
    '='.urlencode($v).
    '&';
  }
  $postData = rtrim($postData, '&');

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

  $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  $response = json_decode($result, true);
  $access_token = $response['access_token'];

  return $access_token;
}

function getLocation($deviceId, $access_token) {
  $locationUrl = "URL";
  $ch = curl_init($locationUrl);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token));
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  return $result;
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i didn't saw the symthax sry,  think you are not using the right username / password.

Anyway i suggest you to have a look at this (php man for setopt-array):

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-setopt-array.php

And also this (man for set_opt)
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-setopt.php